# Finding Eigenvector from a 3x3 matrix

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

Given the constant matrix

A = \begin{bmatrix}4&-1&0\\3&1&-1\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}

Find the fundamental matrix.

After finding the eigenvalue $\lambda$=2 with multiplicity 3, then trying to find the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue, I end up with matrix 
\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&0\\3&-1&-1\\1&0&-1\end{bmatrix}, then after trying to find the corresponding eigenvector I end up with u=(1,2z,z), which I obtained from letting x=1 and subtracting the first and second rows with appropriate multiplication of 3$R_1$ and -2$R_2$ and adding the rows. Also, the reduced matrix has the form

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&1&-2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

Then the first eigenvector u is u=(1,2,1). Nonetheless, since the eigenvalue has muliplicity 2 shouldn't there be two more eigenvectors in terms of some variable t?

Comment: Note that $$A-2I=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&0\\3&-1&-1\\1&0&\color{#f00}{-3}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Are you sure that you wrote the right matrix. I ask this because $2$ is *not* an eigenvalue of the one that you mentioned (in fact, it has no rational eigenvalues). Besides, what is a “fundamental matrix”?

Comment: I apologize I have fixed the matrix, it seems I accidentally added a negative to the element (3,3) it should be just 1, NOT -1

Comment: Eigenvector is $u=(z,2z,z)$ or: any non-zero multiple of $(1,2,1).$

Comment: Thanks I just figured it out, but thanks for confirming my answer! Nonetheless, should there not be 2 more answers since the eigenvalue has a multiplicity of 3?

Comment: The algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $2$ is $3$, but the geometric multiplicity is $1$.

Comment: How do I find the geometric multiplicity? And does the geometric multiplicity dictate how many eigenvectors I'll have?